# Shinking JVM memory and Swap

Tags: jvm, swap

Virtual Machine:

4CPU
10GB RAM
10GB swap

Java 1.7 
-Xms=-Xmx=6144m

Tomcat 7

We observed a very strange behaviour with the JVM. The JVm resident memory began to shrink and the swap usage shot up to over 50%.

Please see below stats from monitoring tools.

http://i44.tinypic.com/206n6sp.jpg
http://i44.tinypic.com/m99hl0.jpg

Any pointers to understand this is grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is more of a Linux system administration question, so it probably belongs on Server Fault, not here. But I'm guessing there's another process that is not showing up on your graph. Use `top` to see all processes and press `M` to sort by memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe your Java program was idle and it didn't need that memory, and you have high swappiness? In such situation your OS would free RAM just in case and leave only used part.

In my opinion, that is actually good behaviour, why should you waste RAM for process that won't use it?

Unless you run only this one process on VM, then it would be quite good idea to set swappiness to 0 or other small number - this memory was given to this single process, so we may disable swapping it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. Yes this is more close to a system troubleshooting than Java but I thought this the right forum to initiate this topic incase anybody has seen such a phenomena with JVM.

Anyways, I had already checked the top and no there was no other process than Java which was hungry for memory. Actually the second top process was utilizing 72MB (RSS).

No the swappiness is not aggressive set on this system but at default 60. One additional information I missed to share is we have 4 app servers in cluster and all showed this behaviour exactly at the same time. AFAIK, JVM does not swap out but the OS would. But all of it is what confusing me.

All these app servers are production and busy serving request so not idle. The used Heap size was at Avg 5 GB used of the the 6GB.

The other interesting thing I found out were some failed messages in the Vmware logs at the same time which is what I'm investigating.